# Magento 1.8 Load More product button showing Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLButtonElement] in console

Tags: magento-1.8, product

Am using **coolbaby** theme in `magento 1.8`. Here am trying to add `load more product`, but i got error message in `console`

> prototype.js:3574 Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLButtonElement]

i refer this link [Reference Link](http://www.uxrim.com/technical/2013/11/26/ajax-loading-of-product-collection-in-project-listing-page-magento/)

to add this code in `app/design/frontend/coolbaby/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

Follwing my code:

**list.phtml**

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
   <button id="load-more-products" class="button btn-info">Load more products</button>
</div>
<script>
   function sendLoadMoreProductsRequest(url) {
            new Ajax.Request(url, {
                onSuccess: function(response) {
                    //Create dummy element
                    var div = document.createElement('div');
                    div.innerHTML = response.responseText;
                    //refresh the page class element
                    $$('.pages')[0].innerHTML = $(div).select('.pages')[0].innerHTML;
                    //append the list to the existing product list
                    $$('.category-products')[0].innerHTML += $(div).select('.category-products')[0].innerHTML;
                    //check if there are more products to be loaded or not
                    if(!$(div).select('.next.i-next')[0]){
                        $('load-more-products').style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            });
         }

         function callbackFunc(e) {
            if($$('.next.i-next')[0]){
                var nextPageUrl = $$('.next.i-next')[0].readAttribute('href');
                sendLoadMoreProductsRequest(nextPageUrl);
            }
            else{
                //hide button
                $$(e.currentTarget).hide();
            }
         }

         //Assigning click event to the button which triggers the "next" link
         $('load-more-products').observe('click', callbackFunc);

</script>
<script>
   //<![CDATA[
          //check if there are more products to be loaded or not
          if($$('.next.i-next')[0]){
              $('load-more-products').style.display = "none";
          }

          function testScroll(ev){
              if($$('.scroll-to-top')[0]){
                  console.log(window.pageYOffset);
                  if(window.pageYOffset>400){
                      $$('.scroll-to-top')[0].style.display = "block";
                  }
                  else{
                      $$('.scroll-to-top')[0].style.display = "none";
                  }
              }
          }
          window.onscroll = testScroll;
      //]]>
</script>
```

When i click `Load more products` button it showing error in `console` and product not loaded.

> Note: Am tried `Strategery / InfiniteScroll` also its not working **coolbaby** theme.

How can i fix this error please help in this...!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `$$` function can take *only* string parameter, but here

```
//hide button
$$(e.currentTarget).hide();
```

You pass html element. Possibly you want single `$` instead:

```
$(e.currentTarget).hide();
```

Comment: Thanks to replay me actually here am pass two arguments. If am remove `$` `<button id="load-more-products" class="button btn-info">Load more products</button>` will be hide in first click

Comment: @RameshS, this depends on result in this condition: `if($$('.next.i-next')[0]){` possibly you need fix your html markup